# Link won't open

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm building a page with a header at the top, a menu on the left and a footer at the borrom. I've defined all of these using .

The link is in the menu. As long as I'm not applying the css, the links work, but as soon as I apply the css that is in an external file it stops working.

I can see it change when I hover and disappear when I click on it, but the page doesn't change.
It only works if I open the link in a new window or in a new tab. Why is it doing this? How can I fix it?

Here's the HTML code :

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Site HTML</h1>      
        </div>

        <div id="menu" >
            <h1>Navigation</h1>
                    <ul>
                            <li>    <a href="javascript.html">Javascript</a>   </li>
                    </ul>

            </div>

            <div id="content"> 
            <p>
            </p>
         </div>

     </body>
```

and here is the CSS for the menu and the link to clic on.

```
#menu {
     min-width:20%;
     max-width:20%;
     min-height:80%;
     max-height:80%;
     background-color:#
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     position:fixed;
     top:10%;
     overflow:auto;
}


#menu li {
     list-style-type:none;
     font:large, arial,sans-serif;  
}   

#menu a:link,a:visited{
     display:block;
     font-weight:bold;
     color:#FF6600;
     background-color:black;
     width:75%;
     text-align:center;
     padding:4px;
     text-decoration:none;  
}

#menu a:hover {color:#0000FF;}   

#menu a:active {visibility:hidden;}
```

Comment: Your CSS is not complete.

Comment: Can you post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: What do you mean by the CSS not being complete and (other dumb question) what's a JSFiddle? :-)

Comment: No hang on, I just got the JSFiddle thing. I'm looking into it.

Comment: Done (and very handy) http://jsfiddle.net/mexican_haze/R6fqa/

Comment: JSFiddle's are very useful for answering questions.:)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `#menu a:active {visibility:hidden;}`

Don't think it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are setting the property visibility hidden on active pseudo class. Just remove the line:

```
#menu a:active {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gomflo/KEq8U/